# Kth Largest Element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve the Kth Largest Element problem.I don't why following bugs appeared. "E: 6,16: Undefined variable 'quickSelect' (undefined-variable)
E: 27,19: Undefined variable 'quickSelect' (undefined-variable)
E: 30,19: Undefined variable 'quickSelect' (undefined-variable)" Here are my codes.

```
def kthLargestElement(self, k, A):
     return quickSelect(A, 0, len(A) - 1, k)

def quickSelect(self, nums, start, end, k):
    if start == end:
        return nums[start]

    i = start
    j = end
    pivot = (nums[start] + nums[end]) // 2

    while i <= j:
        while i <= j and nums[i] < pivot:
            i += 1
        while i <= j and nums[j] > pivot:
            j -= 1
        if i <=j:
            nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    if start + k - 1 <= j:
        return quickSelect(nums, start, j, k)

    if start + k - 1 >= i:
        return quickSelect(nums, i, end, k - (i - start))

    return nums[j + 1]
```

Comment: We need to know how you're calling the functions. Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The presence of `self` as the first parameter to these functions seems to indicate that they are actually methods in a class.  You cannot refer to methods via their name alone: it's always something like `anInstanceOfThisClass.quickSelect(...)`.  On the other hand, the lack of any further references to the `self` parameter indicates that these functions are not benefiting in any way from being methods in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Python cannot find `quickSelect` because it's looking for it in the global namespace rather than looking inside your class. To fix this you can invoke your function using `self.quickSelect(...)` instead of `quickSelect(...)`.